# Printing an array with jquery each and comparing 2 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im having some weird problems with this arrays, what im trying to do first of all is compare two dates within a map array and if its true then i will append it to the container , if its false it wont do anything , but for some reason it does append the div but not the img with the value ;( , if i alert the variable is in there but it doesnt work within the image tag.

So heres what im doing:

```
var sabiasfechas = {
    '2012-01-02': '2012-12-02',
    '2012-01-02': '2012-12-02'
}
sabiasfotos=new Array(2);
sabiasfotos[0] ='sabias1.jpg';
sabiasfotos[1] ='promo-tablet.jpg';


$.each(sabiasfechas,function(key,value){
        $.each(sabiasfotos,function(otrovalue){
            var fechainisab = Date.parse(key);
             var fechafinalsab = Date.parse(value);
             var fechainicomsab = Date.today().compareTo(fechainisab);
             var fechafincomsab = Date.today().compareTo(fechafinalsab);
            if(fechainicomsab == 1 && fechafincomsab == -1){

                $("#imagenescontent").append("<div class='sombra'><img src='img/" + this+ "'/></div>");
            }
            else{
                console.log("nada")
            }
        })



})
```

Any ideas?
Edit: I forgot to close the img tag LOL tnx btw.

Comment: you have no closing ' at the end of your src attribute

Comment: Your welcome :) wanna mark my asnwer? I was cheeky enough to repeat it for the points hehe

Comment: will do just give me 2 mins and tnx :)

Comment: no worries. just one of those pesky typos :) BTW, not sure if you do already..Firebug in FF would have helped pick this up.

Comment: aight ill use that next time tnx a bunch again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have no closing ' at the end of your src attribute